# How to implement recursive function by RISC-V

Tags: recursion, assembly, riscv

I have to solve the recursion question using RISCV code

'question:T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 2n + 7, T(1) = 5'

'I wrote the main function but had some problems.I thought it's because jump part but just couldn't find out what's wrong.After executing,it always output" attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00000000".Can somebody help me to debug?

Thank you for your time!'

```
.globl __start

.rodata
    msg0: .string "This is HW1-1: T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 2n + 7, T(1) = 5\n"
    msg1: .string "Enter a number: "
    msg2: .string "The result is: "

.text


__start:
  # Prints msg0
    addi a0, x0, 4
    la a1, msg0
    ecall`your text`
    
  # Prints msg1
    addi a0, x0, 4
    la a1, msg1
    ecall

  # Reads an int
    addi a0, x0, 5
    ecall
    
################################################################################ 
  # Write your main function here. 
  # Input n is in a0. You should store the result T(n) into t0
  # HW1-1 T(n) = 4T(n/2) + 2n + 7, T(1) = 5, round down the result of division
  # ex. addi t0, a0, 1
T:
   addi sp,sp,-16 #save return address and n on stack
   sw x1,8(sp)
   sw a0,0(sp)
   srli x31,a0,1 #x31=n/2
   addi x30,x0,1 #x30=1
   bne x31,x30,L1 #if n/2!=1,go to L1
   addi t0,x0,5 #else,set return value 5
   addi sp,sp,16  #pop stack
   jalr x0,0(x1)  #return
L1:
   srli a0,a0,1 #n=n/2
   j T  
   addi x7,t0,0
   lw a0,0(sp)
   lw x1,8(sp)
   addi sp,sp,16
   slli  x7,x7,2 #T(n/2)=4T(n/2)
   addi t0,x7,0 #T(n)= 4T(n/2)
   addi t0,t0,7  #T(n)= 4T(n/2)+7
   add x28,x0,a0  #x28=n
   slli x28,x28,1  #x28=2n
   add t0,t0,x28 #T(n)= 4T(n/2)+7+2n
   jalr x0,0(x1)
   
   
   
################################################################################

result:
  # Prints msg2
    addi a0, x0, 4
    la a1, msg2
    ecall

  # Prints the result in t0
    addi a0, x0, 1
    add a1, x0, t0
    ecall
    
  # Ends the program with status code 0
    addi a0, x0, 10
    ecall
```

Comment: It is bad practice and practically unreadable to mix `x` register numbers with friendly register numbers (like `a0`, `ra`, `sp`, etc.).  For everyone's benefit, just stick to the friendly register names (no `x` register names, except `x0` is fine, though you don't really need it since you can use `li` and `mv` to avoid it)!

Comment: Your test main, `__start`, fails to call the function: it simply falls into it.  There should be a function call, and immediately after the call, the rest of the test main code to print results and terminate the program.  The function attempts a return operation, but since it hasn't been properly called, it is folly.

Comment: Let's note that while recursion is part of this exercise, recursion does not impose any new requirements compared with function calling something else other than self.

Comment: And further that the code shown does not actually contain any function calling, recursive or otherwise.

Comment: `j T` is a jump, not a jump-and-link, so when `T` tries to save the return address, it's not saving anything useful. Later, it tries to return to that not-useful value. Stepping through this code in a debugger should have shown you that `x1` held the wrong value after the `j T`.